# Tengo un problema de syntax en mysql

Tags: mysql

```
 [Error - mysql_real_query] Query: UPDATE `players` SET `level` = 8,`group_id` = 5,`vocation` = 4,`health` = 185,`healthmax` = 185,`experience` = 4200,`lookbody` = 106,`lookfeet` = 76,`lookhead` = 78,`looklegs` = 58,`looktype` = 128,`lookaddons` = 0,`maglevel` = 0,`mana` = 40,`manamax` = 40
```

Message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ',`lastlogin` = 1594437914,`lastip` = 16777343,`conditions` = '',`skulltime` = 0' at line 1
Error while saving player:

La verdad no entiendo en donde es que sufro del problema de la syntax

Esta es mi código fuente C++ que hace UPDATE

```
//First, an UPDATE query to write the player itself
query.str(std::string());
query << "UPDATE `players` SET ";
query << "`level` = " << player->level << ',';
query << "`group_id` = " << player->group->id << ',';
query << "`vocation` = " << player->getVocationId() << ',';
query << "`health` = " << player->health << ',';
query << "`healthmax` = " << player->healthMax << ',';
query << "`experience` = " << player->experience << ',';
query << "`lookbody` = " << static_cast<uint32_t>(player->defaultOutfit.lookBody) << ',';
query << "`lookfeet` = " << static_cast<uint32_t>(player->defaultOutfit.lookFeet) << ',';
query << "`lookhead` = " << static_cast<uint32_t>(player->defaultOutfit.lookHead) << ',';
query << "`looklegs` = " << static_cast<uint32_t>(player->defaultOutfit.lookLegs) << ',';
query << "`looktype` = " << player->defaultOutfit.lookType << ',';
query << "`lookaddons` = " << static_cast<uint32_t>(player->defaultOutfit.lookAddons) << ',';
query << "`maglevel` = " << player->magLevel << ',';
query << "`mana` = " << player->mana << ',';
query << "`manamax` = " << player->manaMax << ',';
query << "`manaspent` = " << player->manaSpent << ',';
query << "`soul` = " << static_cast<uint16_t>(player->soul) << ',';
query << "`town_id` = " << player->town->getID() << ',';

const Position& loginPosition = player->getLoginPosition();
query << "`posx` = " << loginPosition.getX() << ',';
query << "`posy` = " << loginPosition.getY() << ',';
query << "`posz` = " << loginPosition.getZ() << ',';

query << "`cap` = " << (player->capacity / 100) << ',';
query << "`sex` = " << player->sex << ',';

if (player->lastLoginSaved != 0) {
    query << "`lastlogin` = " << player->lastLoginSaved << ',';
}

if (player->lastIP != 0) {
    query << "`lastip` = " << player->lastIP << ',';
}

query << "`conditions` = " << db.escapeBlob(conditions, conditionsSize) << ',';

if (g_game.getWorldType() != WORLD_TYPE_PVP_ENFORCED) {
    int64_t skullTime = 0;

    if (player->skullTicks > 0) {
        skullTime = time(nullptr) + player->skullTicks;
    }

    query << "`skulltime` = " << skullTime << ',';

    Skulls_t skull = SKULL_NONE;
    if (player->skull == SKULL_RED) {
        skull = SKULL_RED;
    } else if (player->skull == SKULL_BLACK) {
        skull = SKULL_BLACK;
    }
    query << "`skull` = " << static_cast<int64_t>(skull) << ',';
}

query << "`lastlogout` = " << player->getLastLogout() << ',';
query << "`balance` = " << player->bankBalance << ',';
query << "`offlinetraining_time` = " << player->getOfflineTrainingTime() / 1000 << ',';
query << "`offlinetraining_skill` = " << player->getOfflineTrainingSkill() << ',';
query << "`stamina` = " << player->getStaminaMinutes() << ',';
query << "`charmscoins` = " << player->getCharmCoins() << ',';

query << "`bonusrerollcount` = " << player->getBonusRerollCount() << ',';
query << "`skill_fist` = " << player->skills[SKILL_FIST].level << ',';
query << "`skill_fist_tries` = " << player->skills[SKILL_FIST].tries << ',';
query << "`skill_club` = " << player->skills[SKILL_CLUB].level << ',';
query << "`skill_club_tries` = " << player->skills[SKILL_CLUB].tries << ',';
query << "`skill_sword` = " << player->skills[SKILL_SWORD].level << ',';
query << "`skill_sword_tries` = " << player->skills[SKILL_SWORD].tries << ',';
query << "`skill_axe` = " << player->skills[SKILL_AXE].level << ',';
query << "`skill_axe_tries` = " << player->skills[SKILL_AXE].tries << ',';
query << "`skill_dist` = " << player->skills[SKILL_DISTANCE].level << ',';
query << "`skill_dist_tries` = " << player->skills[SKILL_DISTANCE].tries << ',';
query << "`skill_shielding` = " << player->skills[SKILL_SHIELD].level << ',';
query << "`skill_shielding_tries` = " << player->skills[SKILL_SHIELD].tries << ',';
query << "`skill_fishing` = " << player->skills[SKILL_FISHING].level << ',';
query << "`skill_fishing_tries` = " << player->skills[SKILL_FISHING].tries << ',';
query << "`skill_critical_hit_chance` = " << player->skills[SKILL_CRITICAL_HIT_CHANCE].level << ',';
query << "`skill_critical_hit_chance_tries` = " << player->skills[SKILL_CRITICAL_HIT_CHANCE].tries << ',';
query << "`skill_critical_hit_damage` = " << player->skills[SKILL_CRITICAL_HIT_DAMAGE].level << ',';
query << "`skill_critical_hit_damage_tries` = " << player->skills[SKILL_CRITICAL_HIT_DAMAGE].tries << ',';
query << "`skill_life_leech_chance` = " << player->skills[SKILL_LIFE_LEECH_CHANCE].level << ',';
query << "`skill_life_leech_chance_tries` = " << player->skills[SKILL_LIFE_LEECH_CHANCE].tries << ',';
query << "`skill_life_leech_amount` = " << player->skills[SKILL_LIFE_LEECH_AMOUNT].level << ',';
query << "`skill_life_leech_amount_tries` = " << player->skills[SKILL_LIFE_LEECH_AMOUNT].tries << ',';
query << "`skill_mana_leech_chance` = " << player->skills[SKILL_MANA_LEECH_CHANCE].level << ',';
query << "`skill_mana_leech_chance_tries` = " << player->skills[SKILL_MANA_LEECH_CHANCE].tries << ',';
query << "`skill_mana_leech_amount` = " << player->skills[SKILL_MANA_LEECH_AMOUNT].level << ',';
query << "`skill_mana_leech_amount_tries` = " << player->skills[SKILL_MANA_LEECH_AMOUNT].tries << ',';
query << "`xpboost_value` = " << player->getStoreXpBoost() << ',';
query << "`xpboost_stamina` = " << player->getExpBoostStamina() << ',';

if (!player->isOffline()) {
    query << "`onlinetime` = `onlinetime` + " << (time(nullptr) - player->lastLoginSaved) << ',';
}
for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
    query << "`blessings" << i << "`" << " = " << static_cast<uint32_t>(player->getBlessingCount(i)) << ((i == 8) ? ' ' : ',');
}
query << " WHERE `id` = " << player->getGUID();

DBTransaction transaction;
if (!transaction.begin()) {
    return false;
}

if (!db.executeQuery(query.str())) {
    return false;
}
```

Y esta es la tabla mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `players` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`group_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`account_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`level` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`vocation` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`health` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '150',
`healthmax` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '150',
`experience` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`lookbody` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`lookfeet` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`lookhead` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`looklegs` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`looktype` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '136',
`lookaddons` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`maglevel` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`mana` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`manamax` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`manaspent` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`soul` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`town_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`posx` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`posy` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`posz` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`conditions` blob NOT NULL,
`cap` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`sex` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`lastlogin` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`lastip` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`save` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`skull` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`skulltime` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`lastlogout` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`blessings` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`blessings1` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`blessings2` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`blessings3` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`blessings4` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`blessings5` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`blessings6` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`blessings7` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`blessings8` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`onlinetime` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`deletion` bigint(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`balance` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`offlinetraining_time` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '43200',
`offlinetraining_skill` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
`stamina` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '2520',
`skill_fist` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '10',
`skill_fist_tries` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`skill_club` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '10',
`skill_club_tries` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`skill_sword` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '10',
`skill_sword_tries` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`skill_axe` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '10',
`skill_axe_tries` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`skill_dist` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '10',
`skill_dist_tries` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`skill_shielding` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '10',
`skill_shielding_tries` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`skill_fishing` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '10',
`skill_fishing_tries` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`description` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`comment` text NOT NULL,
`create_ip` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`create_date` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`hide_char` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`cast` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`skill_critical_hit_chance` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`skill_critical_hit_chance_tries` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`skill_critical_hit_damage` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`skill_critical_hit_damage_tries` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`skill_life_leech_chance` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`skill_life_leech_chance_tries` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`skill_life_leech_amount` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`skill_life_leech_amount_tries` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`skill_mana_leech_chance` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`skill_mana_leech_chance_tries` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`skill_mana_leech_amount` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`skill_mana_leech_amount_tries` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`skill_criticalhit_chance` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`skill_criticalhit_damage` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`skill_lifeleech_chance` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`skill_lifeleech_amount` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`skill_manaleech_chance` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`skill_manaleech_amount` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`prey_stamina_1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`prey_stamina_2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`prey_stamina_3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`prey_column` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`charmscoins` int(11) NOT NULL,
`playerid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`bonusrerollcount` int(11) NOT NULL,
`bonus_reroll` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`xpboost_stamina` smallint(5) DEFAULT NULL,
`xpboost_value` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`marriage_status` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`hide_skills` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`hide_set` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`former` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-',
`signature` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`marriage_spouse` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
`loyalty_ranking` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`madphp_signature` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Absolute Mango © MadPHP.org',
`madphp_signature_bg` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Absolute Mango © MadPHP.org',
`madphp_signature_eqs` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Absolute Mango © MadPHP.org',
`madphp_signature_bars` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Absolute Mango © MadPHP.org',
`madphp_signature_cache` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Absolute Mango © MadPHP.org',
`lookmount` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`sbw_points` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`InstantRewardTokens` int(12) DEFAULT NULL,
`charmpoints` int(11) DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

No entiendo por que me marca ese error. Alguien me podría identificar el error, por favor, ya tengo agotado el cerebro y la vista y no lo encuentro.

Adjunto la base de datos mysql, disculpen que la coloque en una página de de post de códigos, porque es largo.

@A. Cedano

LINK DE LA BASE MYSQL: https://pastebin.com/rJ4ka7dn

Comment: ¿Puedes hacer un output de la estructura de la query? Eso ayudará a identificar maás rápido el error

Comment: Pon la consulta completa para revisarla, parece un error de concatenación.

Comment: bueno A. Cadano ahi adjunte a final del tema principal la base completa esperando a tu comentario y ojala se encuentre el problema como digo se me quemo el cerebro con ese error ajajjaajaj

Comment: Revisa que los values antes de **lastlogin** estén en concatenados de acuerdo a su tipo de dato, si te das cuenta el error marca una comilla simple antes de **lastlogin**,  y los values que estás poniendo antes son de tipo **int**, quizá por ahí vaya la cosa.

Comment: creo que em problema esta en el c++ query << "`sex` = " << player->sex << ',';   --------> aqui tendria que llevar comillas igual "dato"  --> ejemplo digame si estoy equivocado